# Generator expression calling a function that returns lists

Tags: python, generator-expression

I have a function that returns a list, and I want to merge the outputs of that function when called on a list using a compact generator expression (or anything nice and compact)

Suppose I have a  `def foo(bar):` where bar is in integer, and it returns a list after some crazy complex computation.

```
foo(1)=[9,1,5]
foo(2)=[1]
foo(3)=[7,1]

arr=[1,2,3]
```

How can I get `arr=[9,1,5,1,7,1]` hopefully after a single line of code?

`arr=[foo(x) for x in arr]` gives me `[[9,1,5],[1],[7,1]]`
 And I'd hate to write another line to roll out the lists within the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
result = list(chain.from_iterable(foo(x) for x in arr))
```